# Sharing saves with different user accounts on the same PS3

Tags: ps3

I recently came home with a shiny PS3 game and my wife and I were so excited to start playing that we didn't pay attention/didn't care which account was currently active. So 2 days later, after 18 hours playtime, she jumped on her user account and there was no option to Load, only to Start New.

I was wondering if anybody knew of a way that I could get the saves between the accounts so that she could play under her name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a relevant thread here about it: http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?450516-PS3-question-Copying-save-files-between-users

Long-story-short: You can copy games between accounts (find the save file, press triangle to access the menu, copy, select destination account), but some games refuse to load saves that were not created by the currently-active account. You'll have to try it out to see.

There's a step-by-step guide to copying saves here: http://www.ehow.com/how_6818656_transfer-data-one-account-another.html

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about the Saved Data section of the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have currently found out by experience that a ps3 can have the saved data on another user. I had a backup flash drive for my ps3 and I had came home one day and my user was deleted and I was wondering why it wouldn't let me load my profile on another user.  So I got to thinking if psn saves your trophies than it should save a file with your user on it. Long story short just sign into psn and ur files should come up, but only if u have a backup.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy games saves finding the save file, press triangle to access the menu, copy, select destination account or to online.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, to do this you will need a flash drive. Plug it into the computer, then format it. Google or Bing psnDataSwitcher. Once downloaded, drag the psnDataSwitcher folder onto the flash drive. Unplug it, and now your done with the computer.

Next, sign into the account on the PS3 that has the saves on it. Plug the flash drive into your PS3. Go to the controller icon, then click "Saved Data Utility". Once you're in there, press Triangle. Click flash drive, and place psnDataSwitcher into the saved data utility.

Comment: Your answer is incomplete; could you please finish it?