# Locked out of the account my Skyrim saves were under - How do I recover it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, psn

My sister had a PS account we have been playing Skyrim on. Somehow she got logged out of the account, and it won't let us save the game anymore, saying it belongs to another player.

She made the account years ago and we don't know the email or passwords used for it only the user name.

Is there a way we can either logged back into her account or save the game on a new one?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103026/sharing-saves-with-different-user-accounts-on-the-same-ps3) StackExchange thread.  It pretty much explains how to transfer saves from one PSN account to another on the same PS3.

Quoted answer by '[YellowMegaMan](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1613/yellowmegaman)' from the other thread:

> There's a relevant thread here about it:
>   http://forum.rpg.net/showthread.php?450516-PS3-question-Copying-save-files-between-users
>
> Long-story-short: You can copy games between accounts (find the save
>   file, press triangle to access the menu, copy, select destination
>   account), but some games refuse to load saves that were not created by
>   the currently-active account. You'll have to try it out to see.
>
> There's a step-by-step guide to copying saves here:
>   http://www.ehow.com/how_6818656_transfer-data-one-account-another.html

Hope it helps!